# How to Use a returned value from a function?

Tags: vb.net

Why this code doesn't work?
it returns an unexpected value actually total = 0.

```
total = Cscore(TextBox1.Text) * CDbl(TextBox2.Text)
```

when trying this

```
total = TextBox1.Text * TextBox2.Text
```

it returns the expected value but I need to pass textbox1.text to the function to get the desirable value

the function is this

```
Public Function Cscore(ByVal score As Integer) As Double

    Select Case score
        Case score = 100
            Return 5.0
        Case score >= 95
            Return 5.0
        Case score >= 90
            Return 4.75
        Case score >= 85
            Return 4.5
        Case score >= 80
            Return 4.0
        Case score >= 75
            Return 3.5
        Case score >= 70
            Return 3.0
        Case score >= 65
            Return 2.5
        Case score >= 60
            Return 2.0
        Case score < 60
            Return 1.0
    End Select
End Function
```

thanks in advance

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer this question if you told us *in what way* the code doesn't work. Does it throw an error? Return an unexpected value, what? Off the top of my head, you're causing an implicit conversion from `string` to `int` by passing the Text property of a Textbox into that function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Option Strict On would have helped you quickly find the problem.  Your syntax for the Case statements is wrong, those expressions evaluate to Boolean.  score will rarely be equal to True or False, you only get a value if score equals 0 or 1.  You need to write it like this:

```
    Select Case score
        Case Is = 100
            Return 5.0
        Case Is >= 95
            Return 5.0
        Case Is >= 90
            Return 4.75
        '' etc...
    End Select
```

Use Option Strict On while you learn to program in VB.NET.  You can turn it off again when you've become a master.

Comment: +1 for good advice in general. Also consider *not* turning Option Strict off, because why not let the compiler catch such mistakes?

Comment: Also if the same result is returned for >=95 and =100 why have both cases? Unless that is an oversimplification for the purposes of the example code.

Comment: @djacobson Option Strict is OFF by default so saying "consider not turning Option Strict off" doesn't make sense. Hans Passant has already said consider turning it ON.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, if the value is greater than 100, then this function doesn't have a return value (it will return the default value for the type - 0 in this instance).

You also should use `Integer.TryParse` to verify all input is an integer before calling a function expecting an Integer.

In the end, I would suggest always having a `case else` on the end of any `select` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Val() function to convert a String to an Integer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

what if you try something along the lines of

```
Dim tb1 as Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
Dim tb2 as Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text)

total = Cscore(tb1) * tb2
```